# Dotnet core 2.1.302 Ubuntu Linux Development certificate trust

Tags: https, cryptography, .net-core

I am running ubuntu 18.04 and I have installed dotnet 2.1.302. I need help in trusting the developer certificates to run my aspnetcore app with https. So far I managed to import the certificates from  /home/alberto/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/ca
and /home/alberto/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/my
in chrome but they still show untrusted.
A search of the web only revealed how to create your own certificate and run it but I just need to use the ones by MS for development if possible.
Any help appreciated!

Cheers,
Alberto

Comment: have you tried `dotnet dev-certs https --trust`

Comment: Yup. Then I read that it's not supported in Linux distros.

Comment: I'm also having the same issue! I followed this blog post to be able to run. But I guess Microsoft should address this in more detail. [Creating and trusting a self-signed Certificate on Linux]( https://andrewlock.net/creating-and-trusting-a-self-signed-certificate-on-linux-for-use-in-kestrel-and-asp-net-core)

Comment: Also having this problem. Running Antergos, reformatted today and git cloned my ongoing project. It ran before but it's having problems running now. The front end SPA on other machine on my LAN gets "unknown error 0". curl from localhost gets "curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate". Running the command to accept the certs does nothing. The Microsoft documentation said that some sort of development certificate was supposed to be created during the first run experience when I first used the SDK.

Comment: @Bill yeah, i saw the blog from Andrew and it will work. My problem is i have several machines and I replicate my code via bitbucket to keep them in sync. So I was trying to avoid having to create specific certs for each machine since netcore should come with its own certs. I wonder if i can just create the cert on one, store it in my project and then use git to propagate it to the other development machines...

Answer (score 1):

**There is no centralized way of trusting the a certificate on `Linux`** so you can do one of the following:

1. Exclude the `URL` you are using in your browsers exclude list
2. Trust all self-signed certificates on `localhost`
3. Add the `https.crt` to the list of trusted certificates in your browser.

See [Configuring HTTPS in ASP.NET Core across different platforms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/configuring-https-in-asp-net-core-across-different-platforms/) and there are documentation links if you are using just [`Kestrel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel) or `Kestrel` with reverse proxy like [`Apache`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache) or [`Nginx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx).